# UITextField border with AutoLayout is flickering

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, autolayout

I am designing screen like a form, containing few `UITextFields` using **AutoLayout**. I wanted to set border only at bottom of the `UITextFields`. I have set border using `CALayer`. But `UITextField` occupies its height(after autolayout is applied to it) in method `viewDidAppear`, so adding border to `UITextField` in `viewDidAppear` makes it appear as if its flickering. So Is there any other way to set border to `UITextFeild` at bottom with **AutoLayout**.

Comment: Have you tried with simple UIView at the bottom of UITextField ?? I mean take UIView of height say 1px and then apply constraints to it so that it will be always attached to the bottom of UITextField.

Comment: Thanks, We can make it work using UIView at bottom of UITextFeild as a border, but i have to toggle color of border between textFieldDidBeginEditing and textFieldDidEndEditing, therefore i was using CALayer.

Comment: Can't you change color of UIView in those methods???

Comment: Yes, Its possible using UIView, we can change color of it, It will just increase number of IBOutlets in Swift file.

Comment: If you don't want to increase number of outlets then apply CALayer programmatically. Anyhow you have to get the desired output.Now it depends on which strategy you want to apply.

Comment: try layoutIfNeeded

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class CustomTextField: UITextField {

required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)!
    self.commonInit()
}

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    self.commonInit()
}

func commonInit() {
    self.borderStyle = .none //To remove default border.

    let bottomBorder = UIView()
    bottomBorder.frame.size = CGSize(width: self.frame.size.width, height: 1)
    bottomBorder.frame.origin = CGPoint(x: 0, y: self.frame.size.height - 1)
    bottomBorder.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
    bottomBorder.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleTopMargin]
    self.addSubview(bottomBorder)
}
```

}

Finally i achieved it by creating CustomUITextField with AutoLayout. Just apply above class to your UITextField in interface builder.

Answer (score 0):

Steps - Select the textfield -> show attribute inspector right panel and select dotted border style . 
Next drag the uilabel into the scene and make it 1.0 and width what do you want, keep the bottom of the textfield. So your problem is solved. This may help you.

Comment: In this case, Using UILabel/UIView with height 1.0 as a border is the only option.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding you, all you have to do to solve your problem is to call the method "to draw the border" in the method above instead of `viewDidAppear`. I guess it can sove your problem.

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    //A UIViewController's overrode method
    //call you method here
}
```

This method is called before the view appears, and after the layout of the subviews. When you're working - changing I mean - layers, you should always use it instead of `viewDidLoad`, for example.

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the simulator to test that. It looks like its flickering but its not.

> If you are scaling the simulator to 25%. The 1px lines appears and
>   disappears when you scroll cause the screen resolution you have is
>   less than the real device resolution.

**Test it while scaling the simulator to 100%. cmd+1**

Comment: Actually it was flickering on both simulator and on actual device. It was happening because autolayout is completly applied to UITextField in method viewDidAppear. And it was not a best practise to set border in viewDidLayoutSubviews.